# Cumsum with reset when 0 is encountered and by groups

Tags: r, data.table

Below is my dataframe, I'd like to get the "yes" column.  I can't seem to get the `cumsum` to reset when it hits the 0 based on the "value" field by "id".  There are other questions like this, but the solutions won't work with my actual dataset.

```
test<- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), value = c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0), yes = c(1,2,0,1,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,0))
```

I've tried this:

```
test <- data.table(test)  # preferred might be: `setDT(test)`

test<-test[, wrong := cumsum(value), by=id]
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, i've edited the post to have a yes column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new by variable on the fly like this:

```
test[, wrong := cumsum(value), by=.(id, tempID=cumsum(value==0))]
test
    id value correct wrong
 1:  1     1       1     1
 2:  1     1       2     2
 3:  1     0       0     0
 4:  1     1       1     1
 5:  2     1       1     1
 6:  2     1       2     2
 7:  2     1       3     3
 8:  2     1       4     4
 9:  3     0       0     0
10:  3     1       1     1
11:  3     1       2     2
12:  3     0       0     0
13:  4     1       1     1
14:  4     1       2     2
15:  4     0       0     0
16:  4     0       0     0
```

Note that `test <-` is not necessary here, as `:=` will update the data.table by reference.

Comment: Some similar approaches: `test[, v := if (value[1L]) 1:.N else 0L, by=rleid(id, value)]` or `test[, v := rowid(rleid(id, value))*value]` -- should work so long as value is 1/0.

Comment: Can you educate me on one thing: what is cumsum(value==0) doing?

Comment: It's creating a "counter" that increases only at rows where that conditions is met. Thanks, Imo (and Matt). Pretty slick syntactic expression. @Frank: do you know if your more verbose approach has any advantages? And couldn't you force `value` to be 0/1 by making it a logical construction?

Comment: @42- I'm counting 1, 2, 3 on the assumption that the value is 1. To extend to where it might be something else, I guess I'd switch from `1:.N` to `cumsum(value)` and use `rleid(id, value == 0)` as you suggested in the first case, while the second wouldn't extend (as far as I can see). I think the second way might be advantageous in terms of efficiency since it doesn't involve `by=` grouping. Even the first way might be relatively efficient (since it's just enumerating sequences instead of summing)... I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer by Imo could be an advertisement for the ta.table package (as if it needed yet another one for such a great package.) But I also think that base-R solutions should be attempted, so here's mine. It uses `ave` (which requires the FUN argument to be named) and does the cumsum operation twice, the first application is to create a grouping vector, and the second application creates the sequence. The second application could have also been `seq.int` but it would have seemed a bit clumsy since it would have needed to be `function(x)seq.int(0,length(x)-1)` since the default call to seq.int starts from 1 rather than 0.

```
test$yes2 <- ave(test$value, cumsum(test$value==0), FUN=cumsum)

> test
   id value yes yes2
1   1     1   1    1
2   1     1   2    2
3   1     0   0    0
4   1     1   1    1
5   2     1   1    2
6   2     1   2    3
7   2     1   3    4
8   2     1   4    5
9   3     0   0    0
10  3     1   1    1
11  3     1   2    2
12  3     0   0    0
13  4     1   1    1
14  4     1   2    2
15  4     0   0    0
16  4     0   0    0
```

Comment: The `ave` should group by `test$id` as well, right? Also, typo `seq_int` vs probably `seq.int`

Comment: Not sure about the first. Didn't seem like that was requests by natural language or implied by example. Fixed second.